# Using docker instead of ctr not working on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, ctr

I'm trying to use docker instead of ctr on an Ubuntu EC2 node of an EKS Cluster.
Using `ctr -n k8s.io container ls` works, but i want to switch to docker.
The problem is that i get the error `Get "http://%2Frun%2Fcontainerd%2Fcontainerd.sock/v1.24/containers/json": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00@\x00". * Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?` when I try `sudo docker container ls`
The dockerd is running with the folowing parameters: `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_ADD_RUNTIMES`
I created an k8s docker context that uses the EKS endpoint, but with no success.

Comment: I tried adding `--tls` to the dockerd command, but then it failes with `failed to create API server: Could not load X509 key pair (cert: "", key: ""): open : no such file or directory` error